# Filling out array values on "negative" positions

Tags: c, arrays

I have an array with some values in it, eg.
`ABCDEF` and what I need to do is when I want to print out for example first 4 chars `ABCD`, I want to print 3 chars which are in front of first char and 3 chars after last char: `---ABCDEF-` As you can see, `-` is substituting char because there is nothing in front of it and thats what I am trying to do. Those 3 --- are on positions -3 -2 -1 but how can I do it when array goes from 0? Or is there any other easier way to do it? And also put chars after those 4 that I want to print out.

Hope I explained it good enough.

Here is what I have now, same as in description:

```
printf("%d %c%c%c%s%c%c%c\n", h+1, pole[h-3], pole[h-2], pole[h-1], slovo, pole[h+dlzka], pole[h+dlzka+1], pole[h+dlzka+2]);
```

Comment: I dont see a reason for voting it down, I added a code which is same like in the description, Im asking for an idea how should I do it, not the exact code to use. Thank you.

Comment: define a new array with size[12] and go in a loop and check index and populate i and i+2? What's difficulty?

Comment: How are you determining that you should be at a negative index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char original[16] = "ABCDEF";
    char other[16] = {0};
    size_t len = strlen(original);
    memset(other, '-', len + 4);
    memcpy(other + 3, original, len);
    puts(other);
    sprintf(other, "---%s-", original);
    puts(other);

    memmove(original + 3, original, len);//move to back + 3
    memset(original, '-', 3);
    original[len+3] = '-';
    puts(original);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is it going to put `-` every time even when the original array changes? cause I see you have `---%s-` so thats why I am asking. The original array can be also ABCDEF and then output should be `---ABCDEF`.. and many other combinations..

Comment: @febeks The first half, I be stored in another array. Second part to change the original. Both are just a sample code.